# Empty thebibliography environment, but reference loaded

Tags: bibliographies

I have this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, twoside, nocenter,bold]{thesis}

\usepackage{notoccite}

 \begin{document}
 \cite{Moulijn.2001}. 

 \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
 \bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

In my bibliography I have:

```
@article{Moulijn.2001,
author = {Moulijn, J.A and van~Diepen, A.E and Kapteijn, F.},
year = {2001},
title = {Catalyst deactivation: is it predictable?},
pages = {3--16},
volume = {212},
number = {1-2},
issn = {0926-860X},
journal = {Applied Catalysis A: General},
doi = {10.1016/S0926-860X(00)00842-5}
}
```

I get the warning `Empty thebibliography environment` but at the same time the reference is `[2]`, as it should be in the original text, not in the MWE (shouldn't it be `[1]`?). I am very confused.
**What is happening? What am I doing wrong?**

Could it be a matter of editing and re-editing the same document? It used to work before.

Comment: There can be many issues. Mine is the conflict with package EasyReview, which TexStudio uses as comment functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved making sure that the filepaths matched and running the classic BiBTeX sequence, instead of the one from TeXMaker.